# plotting gamma distribution in R with ~Gamma(1000,20)

Tags: r, statistics, gamma-distribution

I'm still relatively new to R and I'm confused on how I'm supposed to plot gamma
My data is distributed ~ Gamma(1000,20)

so my code looks like

```
curve(dgamma(x, shape = 1000 , scale = 20, log = FALSE))
```

This results in a straight line being plot. I am pretty sure it has to do with my value of shape being so high. But the only reason it is 1000 is because I thought shape is a paramter equivalent to alpha (so 1000). Am I wrong? Does shape equal something else? Or is my issue somewhere else?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to set the range of the x-axis, e.g. `curve(dgamma(x, shape = 1000 , scale = 20, log = FALSE), from = 0, to = 2000)`. The parameters are explained in the help page `?dgamma`.

Comment: Its depend on `x`? whats `x`?

Comment: @SRhm: In `curve()`, you can write `x` in an expression and `curve` will evaluate the expression, substituting in different `x` values based on the `from` and `to` args. The example code is fine, it doesn't need a separate `x` variable to be defined.

Comment: @Marius You are right @ajdawg should increase the range like: `curve(dgamma(x, shape = 1000 , scale = 20, log = FALSE), from = 1000, to = 40000)`